# Btrfs write speed very slow. In Linux how do I copy files using page cache?

Tags: linux, filesystems, cache, btrfs, fedora-33

I have 2 filesystems consisting of the same 15Tib size with both of them using 4 nvme ssd of the same model using btrfs based raid0 with all of the them plugged to a pci port.

Both filesystem are filled at around 50% and contains about the same number of files. Both are formated using the same options and mounted using the same mount options which is `nodatasum,commit=3600,discard,inode_cache,max_inline=4096,space_cache=v2,ssd,user_subvol_rm_allowed,noatime,compress=no`.

## The problem

- When I do copy large files on the first filesystem, everything is cached in ram (up to 300Gib). After, the copy is finished the sync command takes hours to complete but the speed remains acceptable.
- Copying from the second filesystem yields speeds of several Gb/s. But when I do copy large files to the second filesystem using the same tool, even after a fresh restart, the write speed is very slow: Only 20Mib/s. At such speed copying Terabytes of new data is a week long process.

I’ve no ideas on what is causing such speed worst than an on hard drive. As such low speed, kernel page caching is definitely not used because otherwise copying the first 300Gib would takes seconds whereas such slow speed starts from the beginning.

Since it seems to be a software issue rather than an hardware issue, I’m thinking that if the kernel page cache would be used regardless of the underlying filesystem performance, the write speed achieved through `umount` would be more normal thereby avoid the underlying problem.

**There are lot of documentation on how to use direct I/O for copying but how I can do the reverse which is copying with never using direct I/O**? I’m meaning to always use the kernel page caching?

Comment: Is TRIM enabled for the slow drives? [Fedora Looking At Finally Enabling FSTRIM By Default In Fedora 32](https://www.phoronix.com/forums/forum/software/distributions/1146906-fedora-looking-at-finally-enabling-fstrim-by-default-in-fedora-32)

Comment: @AndrewMorton look at the mount option in the post. I always used trim on both filesystems. **determining the root cause is likely to be to hard so that the workaround is to always ensure the kernel throttle speed only if the cache is full**.

Comment: [This article on fstrim](https://opensource.com/article/20/2/trim-solid-state-storage-linux) mentions "Using this option [discard] causes a TRIM to be initiated every time new data is written to the drive. This may introduce additional activity that interferes with storage performance."

Comment: @AndrewMorton yes, but only on data deletion and not on newly written data. Yes it somewhat heart out of drive file moving and deletion performance but this isn’t what my question is about.